# Is it possible to apply several pipeline to one Github repository?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would ask you a question about Jenkins :

**Is it possible to apply several pipeline to one github repository ?**

If yes, someone can help me with tutorial our documents or other things ?

*I've tryed to do this with the BlueOcean plugin but this seems impossible ...*

I would like to apply 6 pipepline on one github repository triggerd by events so this question is essential to me !

Comment: You should show what have you done so far?

Comment: I've got my github repo with 2 folder: Dev and Prod, 1 jenkinsfile (which contain one pipeline this pipeline execute some tests on Dev). I don't know what i can add to say :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a job on Jenkins you bind it to a repo.

If you create two jobs and bind them both to the same repo they will both be triggered when you push to your repo. Then you attach your pipelines to these jobs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i will try this way !

Answer (score 0):

You can create pipeline jobs pointing at different build scripts (ie, filenames other than /Jenkinsfile) in the repo or different branches just fine. I do it all the time.

However, be aware that any scm polling you do on the repo/branch could prevent other jobs from identifying changes depending on how you are triggering them.